# insert document in array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm not good at mongodb, so it is hard to manipulate sub documents. What I want to do is implement address book like this:

```
{
    [user1@mail.com]: [
        {
            email: 'aaa@example.com',
            createdAt: '0000-00-00',
            updatedAt: '0000-00-00'
        }
    ],
    [user@mail.com]: [
        { ... },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

I called that collection 'addressbook', and each item is Array type to contain address information like email, image, date of created something like that.

The problem is I don't know how to do it. Looks like I need to use some operators like $addToSet or $push, but I don't get it how to use them correctly. What I tried:

```
update({
    email: 'user1@mail.com'
}, {
    $push: {
        'address.$email': {
            email: target,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date()
        }
    }
})
```

One thing I knew was using upsert option to update collection makes new document if it doesn't exists, but still docs are not creating. It will be very appreciate to gimme a hand.

Comment: so u want to push data into mongoDB right?

Comment: You might have some trouble nesting the documents so deeply like that. Mongo has had trouble updating deeply nested documents.

Comment: You're on the right track, you would use `$push` or `$pull` to add or remove content to or from an existing document.

Comment: oh, thanks. i forgot to tell this is mongodb.

Comment: Please show valid BSON document not *pseudo-document*.

Comment: i haven't created yet because the query doesn't work. i tried in Mongo shell directly, and it saids: "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$email' in 'address.$email' is not valid for storage".

Comment: What exactly you want to do with `'address.$email'`? Your requirement is not so clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like structure presented will hold all user data in one document. This could be very tricky in future handling, as bson document have 16MB capacity limit.

If you could consider simpler form of document:

```
{
   _id:bsonId,       
   email: 'aaa@example.com',
   createdAt: '0000-00-00',
   updatedAt: '0000-00-00',
   name: "unknown"
 }
```

then updating and maintaining your collection will be a lot easier.

```
db.addressbook.update({ email: 'aaa@example.com'},{name:"Happy User"})
```

Comment: oh... i forgot to limit of each document. i should try it. thanks :)